How to share task files among community users of the same partner account?
I wanted to share the tasks assigned to partner users to other users of the same partner account, so that file attachments under the tasks can be shared with the partner users. There is no TaskShare object for Apex Sharing to achieve this. CaseShare or AccountShare does not seem to provide Task access to other users.
Currently I am showing the tasks to other users in the community using LWC in the case page with system permission, and I show that they have files under them with an icon. The requirement is to now to show the file attachments on click of the image icon, but without Task access this could not be provided. I tried to fetch the VersionData of the file in LWC as system user  and show the contents as a popup, but this also seems to have limitations with content being displayed blank and could also end up in file size restrictions.
Is there a way to share these tasks or their files with other partner users given the above restrictions?
